# Apache 302 redirects on download of large (700+MB files)

Tags: apache, file

My Apache server is redirecting when I try download large files in a directory. Smaller files work just fine

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `curl -vI http://your.srv/huge.avi` say?

Comment: * About to connect() to asset.cisco.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.35.48.183...
* connected
* Connected to asset.cisco.com (10.35.48.183) port 80 (#0)
> GET /mcet/software/opp2013.bin HTTP/1.1
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: https://asset.cisco.com/mcet/software/opp2013.bin
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Closing connection #0